# Do Apex tests (have to) run as part of the deployment when we deploy Processes and autolaunched Flows?

Tags: apex, deployment, code-coverage, visual-workflow, process

When you have enabled the setting ['deploy processes and flows as active'](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_admin_deploy_active.htm) you need 75% of Processes and Autolaunched flows to have at least some Apex code coverage.

The documentation on [Running Apex Tests on a Deployment to Production](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy_running_tests.htm) is not 
clear whether deploying Flows or Processes will force Apex tests to run, or just rely on previous Apex test runs to determine whether Flows are covered.

Do such deployments trigger running all tests? Do we need to run specified tests that provide coverage? Or does it just rely on previous test results?

Answer (score 0):

The tests are run whether you deploy the flow as active or not, as stated here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy_running_tests.htm

> If the deployment includes components for the following metadata types, all local tests are run.
>
> Flow

Comment: thanks for responding to this. This doesn't quite answer the question, since that was the behavior 4 years ago, but not the behavior for recent versions of the API. I've made some proposed edits to your response to qualify this answer.